# 'alembic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I already installed via python -m pip install alembic in machine, but I am getting error:

`'alembic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

I even tried to add in pycharm -> file -> settings -> project -> python interpreter -> package, still not resolved.

I am expecting don't want to see this error,

'alembic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I want to execute `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Adding new column"` but it throws the shown error.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment or a default installation? The error message tells you that `alembic` hasn't been added to a directory that's on your current path - i.e. the command won't be found unless it's available in one of the directories you've added to the path. Exactly which directories that are depends on your Python installation.